# Delete() and Deleteall() in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, list

Consider the below two methods to delete a Set of Employees with the name "John" .

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
String query=   " from Employee emp where emp.name = 'John'";
list=getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
```

First Method:

```
 getHibernateTemplate().deleteAll(list);
```

Second Method:

```
Iterator<BulkChangeRequest> itList = list.iterator();
    while(itList.hasNext()) {
        Employee emp = itList.next();
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(emp);
    }
```

Do they differ significantly in terms of performance? Are both of them essentially the same i.e. does the deleteAll method delete row one by one?

Also wouldn't it be better to do it in SQL using the following query?

```
" delete from Employee where name = 'John'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It would be better to use SQL or HQL to delete all employee records named 'John' rather then the first option. Simply because in first option, you have to load all employee record from db to delete. That's obviously an extra task.

I think, for `delete()` and `deleteAll()`, there will be no difference except in `delete()`, it will create new session for every call; whereas in `deleteAll()`, all objects will be deleted in one session. But the number of queries will be the same.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but between the first two methods (delete() and deleteAll() ), is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this section, `one shot delete`:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections-oneshotdelete

> Deleting collection elements one by one can sometimes be extremely
>   inefficient. Hibernate knows not to do that in the case of an
>   newly-empty collection (if you called list.clear(), for example). In
>   this case, Hibernate will issue a single DELETE.